# Continue using LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp library (deprecation)

Tags: android, android-async-http

I need to communicate with our REST-API. I found the [LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) library, but I am not sure if it is a good idea to use it, because it seems to use the HttpClient which is now deprecated in Android API 22. I found [this apache project](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html), but I am not sure if I simply can add this to my project and it will work with AndroidAsyncHttp. Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: Try Volley  https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android volley library is an excellent solution for http requests:

https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

It provides three common request types: StringRequest, JsonObjectRequest and ImageRequest but you can write your custom request also.
It is easy to learn and you have ton of examples on the web.

Comment: Yes! Definitely is the way to go, as documentation suggests. You can find info on how to use it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is maybe the solution, although it seems to be used more fore simple calls API -> getJSON -> update UI. My update strategy will look a bit more complicated (I HAVE to query all updates at app start). But I will give it a try.

Comment: Volley is a piece of crap, you can't even send normal POST requests, instead it needs to be json what you send